# Building executable jar file from .class files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, sharpen-tool

I am trying to build the project Sharpen by versant. I will start out that I don't know anything really about java and it's tools, hence why I am trying to build Sharpen(Java to C# converter). So I ended up building the project, but now I am left with a bunch of .class files in the bin directories.

How can I turn those .class files into a executable .jar file so I can run it? Sharpen is an eclipse plug in, so will I need to do anything extra, and will I have to manually remove files from their subdirectories in the bin folder and add them to the main bin directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Go to file->export->JAR file,
```

select "Export generated class files and sources" and make sure that your project is selected, and all folder